# image not scaling well

Tags: html, css, image

I have a `div` that contains dynamically generated images, now each image has different proportional, now my image is not scaling as per image proportional.

Expected result:

[image]

Here is my solution so far

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.conatiner_box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 5px solid rgb(232, 159, 42);
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="conatiner_box">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HP3tksz/image1.jpg" class="image-box">
   </div>
   <div class="conatiner_box">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Jz9cW7W/image2.jpg" class="image-box">
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6m0hs2qk/)

What do I need to do to solve this?

Comment: For absolute images "CSS trick" you should also use `object-fit` `contain` for the image (Otherwise the image stretch 100% w/h of the relative wrapper). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your images to be responsive, you must set:

```
max-width:100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

Instead of `width` and `height`.

Also remove your position absolute that were not needed

DEMO:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.conatiner_box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 5px solid rgb(232, 159, 42);
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-box {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /*position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;*/
  transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="conatiner_box">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HP3tksz/image1.jpg" class="image-box">
   </div>
   <div class="conatiner_box">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Jz9cW7W/image2.jpg" class="image-box">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow I only knew about `object-fit`. This is new for me! Thanks.

Comment: You welcome, I guess question is answered. Use it well !

Answer (score -2):

You should remove position: absolute from .image-box and remove display: flex; from .conatiner_box. Also image should have width: 100%; and height: auto;
If you want all boxes to have same dimensions you should then define both width and height and use object: fit; Like that you can treat  same as background-image in CSS(but it will not work in Internet Explorer, check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=object-fit)).

Also you should try to have images with similar ratio for better UI.